# How to put a lot of information in the class?

Tags: php, array, classes

I have such a problem:

I'm parsing a lot of HTML files with Simple HTML DOM Parser, that's why I need to use three `foreach`s to parse the necessary information from it -> I am getting a lot of information and now I have three arrays which keep it. I think that it's dumb to keep the code like that and I want to keep the information in the class.

How can I do it in a right way? I really need your advice to have a good code in the future

Here is the code with three arrays:

```
if(count($infos->find('.products-list-item')))
{
    foreach ($infos->find('.products-list-item product-label, .products-list-item .products-list-item__brand, .products-list-item .products-list-item__type,.products-list-item .price') as $item_info) 
    {
        $item_info_arr[] = $item_info->plaintext;
        $i=0;
    }

    foreach ($infos->find('.products-list-item__img') as $img) 
    {
        $src_arr[] = $img->src;
    }

    foreach ($infos->find('.products-list-item .products-list-item__sizes') as $sizes_info) 
    {
        while($size = $sizes_info->children($k++))
        {
            $sizes_arr[] = $size->plaintext;
        }

        $k=0;
    }   

} else {echo "not found";}
```

But what can I do, then?

Answer (score 2):

Please provide some more information, like the example contents of `$infos`. It is hard to find any other solution if we are not able to understand your current solution in the first place.

However, there already are some issues with your code:

- avoid using variable names like `$i` and `$k`. They should be named according to their meaning (see example for `$k`)
- `$i` seems not to be read in your code
- `$k` and all arrays seem to be used uninitialized

Your while loop seems a bit too clever to me. All you want to do is iterate $k so you should instead use a for loop:

```
for($childIndex = 0; $size = $sizes_info->children($childIndex); ++$childIndex)
    $sizes_arr[] = $size->plaintext;
```

The foreach loops look as if they could be better implemented by `array_map`:

```
$item_infos = $infos->find('.products-list-item product-label, .products-list-item .products-list-item__brand, .products-list-item .products-list-item__type,.products-list-item .price');
$get_plaintext = function($item_info) { return $item_info->plaintext; };
$item_info_arr = array_map($get_plaintext, $item_infos);
```

A foreach loop could be as readable however then you should at least use named variables (like `$item_infos` but with better names (I have no idea what this find returns)) to keep the head of the loop short and readable.